# How to open a file from a userform and modify it with the userform open

Tags: vba, excel

I have a userform with checkboxes, textfields and the normal usual things on it, including a button that I'd like to use to open a excel spredsheet. This is easy enough to do:

```
Private Sub CMB2_Click()
    Workbooks.Open Filename:="G:\Formular.xlsm"
End Sub
```

When doing this though, the file can not be worked on; in other words, it is not active. The from is active, and until the form is closed or cancelled, the file is locked. I call it locked for a lack of a better description.

If I make the form modeless, all fields in the form loose their function, except the buttons but at least I can work in the opened spreadsheet.

```
UserForm1.Show vbModeless
```

How can I get both? I want to work in the opened spreadsheet and continue on the form when done.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the behavior. I can work on the opened workbook and at the same time all controls (checkboxes, textboxes,button) are functioning perfectly...

Comment: That is odd... I have tried on both Office 2007 and 2010 and both times it locks the opened file. What version have you tested it on ?

Comment: I tested it in xl2010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to open other files in new excel instance. following code will do this for you

```
Dim xlApp as Excel.Application
set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
xlApp.Visible = True
xlApp.Workbooks.Open FileName:="G:\Formular.xlsm"
```

Comment: BRILLIANT.. thank you. Working in Office 2007, taking it will work in 2010 as well ?

Comment: @Sinbad yes this method works in Excel 2010 as well. Remember to `xlApp.Quit` and `Set xlApp = Nothing` at the end!